# Why can't Mako locate a template beside the one that's including it?

Tags: python, linux, mako

Ok, running this in python:

```
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from mako.template import Template
mylookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['/home/user/webapps/app/www/templates/'])
mytemplate = Template(filename='/home/user/webapps/app/www/templates/content.html.mako', lookup=mylookup)
print (mytemplate.render(title="Title", content={'hi'}))
```

When this is the begining of content.html.mako

```
## content.html.mako
<%inherit file="frame.html.mako"/>
```

Gives me this:

```
mako.exceptions.TemplateLookupException: Cant locate template for uri '/home/user/webapps/app/www/templates/frame.html.mako'
```

But the `frame.html.mako` is in the same directory as the `content.html.mako`, what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After posting this I found it works if the 4th line is `mytemplate = mylookup.get_template('content.html.mako')` instead.

Comment: But mako still won't work if your template includes another template with a relative path.